# Emacs - scroll automatically when inserting text

Tags: emacs, elisp

This is driving me nuts and I've been on it all day.

I am trying to write a process filter for communicating with a serial device. That works OK, but when I insert text in to a buffer, I want the buffer to scroll so I can see the text, just like it does when you *type* text in to a buffer. I insert text into several buffers showing different information on the serial line. As it is, every time I issue a serial command I have to drag each scrollbar down so I can see the text.

Changing 'point' just changes the insertion point - the window scrolling doesn't follow. Attempts to call scrolling functions and 'recenter' seem to do nothing. How do I get the windows to scroll?

I'd also like to change the buffer so you can't type in to it, or change the position of 'point' by clicking in the window. Is there a mode that I should be using or something?

Many thanks if anyone can help,

David.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect your problem comes from the fact that point position is not attached to a buffer, but to the window displaying the buffer (since you can have different windows displaying the same buffer at different locations).

You could try something like this:

```
(with-selected-window (get-buffer-window YOUR-BUFFER)
  (goto-char (point-max)))
```

Answer (score 2):

You might like to `(set (make-local-variable 'window-point-insertion-type) t)` in your buffer.

Comment: What does this value do, Stefan? The docstring says the variable specifies a type of marker, but it's not clear to me what a value of `t` means in this respect.

Comment: It means that when text is added right where the window's cursor is located the cursor should stay after that new text rather than before.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. Perhaps that variable could be documented in more detail? That said, it sounds as if I should see a difference in behaviour between `nil` and `t` for that variable, if I `M-: (insert "foo") RET` into the buffer, but the result seems the same in either case, so I'm still a bit confused about this.

Comment: This variable is only effective for those windows which are not the currently selected-window.  For the selected window, the behavior is normally similar to having a value `t` (e.g. in your above `insert` example, the cursor ends up after `foo` rather than before).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for you help with this. If it's of any use to anyone, this is what I've come up with so far and it seems to work.

```el
(defun append-to-buffer (buffer string)
  "Append the text to the end of a buffer"
  (let ((win (get-buffer-window buffer)))
    (if (eq win nil)
        (progn
          (with-current-buffer buffer
            (goto-char (point-max))
            (insert string)))
      (with-selected-window
          (get-buffer-window buffer)
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (insert string)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

`(goto-char (point-max))` should scroll the buffer to the end. The active cursor can't be outside the viewport in Emacs. Are you wrapping your calls in one of the excursion saving commands?

To disallow editing, do `(toggle-read-only 1)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply Magnar. I have (goto-char (point-max)) in my code. It successfully sends point to the end of the buffer. But when I insert my text (insert <my-string>) it eventually runs off the bottom of the window and I have to keep dragging the scrollbar down to keep up with my output.

Comment: I do wrap in an excursion command. I'm doing this from ielm. I don't know if that makes a difference. For example, if you have a buffer open called 'xbee.el' and type (with-current-buffer "xbee.el" (goto-char (point-min)) (insert "some text")) into ielm, the text will go in to the start of the "xbee.el" buffer but you don't see it until you scroll to it (assuming it's off screen).